# DragDrop and Still Click

Tags: .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

Using ListView with GridView with drag and drop

Drag and drop is working

What is broken is two checkbox columns

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Content="" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AppliedDispGrid, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

What is breaking the checkbox the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown
How can I get drag drop and still get a click to the checkbox?

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="lbFields" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource fieldDefsApplied}}"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                    AllowDrop="True"
                    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                    DragDrop.Drop="ListView1_DragDrop" >
```

Tired splitting it in MouseDown and MouseMove but MouseDown event is not called.